# What 'HD' series is the RADEON Mobility X1400?

Tags: graphics-card

What 'HD' series is the X1400 from the list below?

Radeon™ HD 5800 Series
Radeon™ HD 5700 series
Radeon™ HD 4870
Radeon™ HD 4850
Radeon™ HD 4600 series
Radeon™ HD 4500 series
Radeon™ HD 3850
Radeon™ HD 3600 series
Radeon™ HD 3400 series

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. It predates HD series.

Interesting link is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X1400).

Comment: I have another question: Would a FireGL 256 GPU be an improvement 3D-wise over a RADEON X1400 128? Also would a FireGL bring me closer to the 21st century in such a way as to be able to more easily install Windows 7 drivers for it directly from the AMD site? If so I'll buy a new system board for my notebook.

Comment: @user33666  I think that FireGL should have better drivers, but I can't say anything right now. Can you give me a link with a description of the board you are considering? I'll have to take a look around to be sure.

Comment: It's just a ThinkPad T61 replacement board.  Already I know I'd pick up an improvement in the FSB speed:  800 vs. the 667 I have in there now.  Come to think of it that's probably enough of a reason for me to do it.

Comment: @user33666 I was unable to find details about a specific card called FireGL 256, so you'll have to ask someone else familiar with that card. Here's a list of FireGL mobile cards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ATI_graphics_processing_units#Mobility_FireGL.2FFirePro_series